# Using a singleton to talk to an Android Service

Tags: android, android-service

My Android app runs a service instance that is not accessible from other apps.  I know that the service runs in the same process the app's Activity, because I can read and write to a static variable on the Service class from the activity and the Service sees the changes.

Communicating with the service via static variables/methods (or more properly singletons), is much, much simpler than communicating with it using a Handler or an Intent, which requires making all passed parameters Parcelable.  It seems like these two communication methods are really designed for services running in a separate process, and are unnecessary  overhead for an in-process service.

It seems like I must be missing something big.   What is wrong with using a singleton to talk to a service if you know it is local to your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communicating between a Service and an Activity is one of the main reasons to use a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html): you can build a [Binder](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) class that defines the interface between your Service and Activity and pass any objects you want between them without having to worry about parcelling them (as binders require both to be on the same process).

Comment: I see.  So the Binder simply allows you to get the actual instance of the service, so you can make method calls directly on it.  This way you don't need a singleton to make calls.